# FTP Directory subfolders efficiency

Tags: c#, directory

I have about 7000 folders on a FTP server. 300 of these will contain a subfolder named "ToSpecialFolder". I'm using the code below to return the wanted subfolders.

The call takes some time to complete, is there a more efficient way?

```
string[] ftpDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(ftpRootFolder, folderEndsWith, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Are you threading your connection? Most FTP servers will allow 10 or more concurrent connections - might as well use as many as you can as long as specific order is not absolutely imperative.